# Sequelize ERRCONNREFUSED to mysql db in docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

When booting up my api/app/db in docker compose the api is unable to connect to the mysql container.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
        container_name: vue-ui-v2
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/usr/src/app/ui
            - /usr/src/app/ui/node_modules
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
            - api
    api:
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
        ports:
            - "4000:4000"
        container_name: node-api-v2
        volumes:
            - ./backend:/usr/src/app/api
            - /usr/src/app/api/node_modules
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        cap_add:
            - SYS_NICE
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=thebooks
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=defaultPassword
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  db:
```

docker file for api

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

And connect call from sequelize:

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('thebooks', 'root', 'defaultPassword', {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        dialect: 'mysql'
      });
```

I feel like there must be something simple i'm missing, but I've been scratching my head for hours trying to follow this: https://www.bezkoder.com/docker-compose-nodejs-mysql/ and failing for a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to connect to `localhost`

By using localhost it will try to reach to container's localhost

You should use instead the name of the service `db`

Since compose will create by default a bridge network. Your **API** container will be able to resolve the **database** container IP by the name of the service

Change

```
 host: 'localhost',
 port: 3306,
 ...
```

To

```
 host: 'db',
 port: 3306,
 ...
```

Comment: Answer is meaningless. You *always* connect *from* `localhost`. The OP is trying to connect *to* `localhost`.

Comment: @user207421 This was a typo thanks for pointing out, updated answer. The OP is trying to connect to localhost I meant to say.

Comment: @TolisGerodimos Thank you so much. It indeed worked and the explanation was very clear.

Comment: @lalibelamonk Glad to be of help. Good day